# Why does align character & remove horizontal space?

Tags: spacing, align, horizontal

This is something I've been wondering and annoyed about for a long time but cannot find an answer to.

Assume that I have a chain of equations:

```
\begin{align*}
    a &= b \\
      &= c
\end{align*}
```

looking like

[image]

Now assume that the terms in `a` and `b` are just too long to put both of them into one line.
Therefore, I would like to break the line after `a`, continue with the equals sign in the next line, and have `a`, `b` and `c` aligned - so I try:

```
\begin{align*}
      &a \\
    = &b \\
    = &c
\end{align*}
```

However, this produces the output

[image]

so that the horizontal space between the equals sign and the terms is too small. It seems to me that this is because I try to use the align character & to the right side of the equals sign instead of the left side, because it works fine like this:

```
\begin{align*}
    &= a \\
    &= b \\
    &= c
\end{align*}
```

produces

[image]

My only idea for a workaround to get rid of the equals sign in the first line was to just add a phantom:

```
\begin{align*}
    &\hphantom{=} a \\
    &= b \\
    &= c
\end{align*}
```

but firstly it does not work anyway (why??):

[image]

and secondly, if I start to use different characters (<, \Leftrightarrow, ...) that have different sizes, I need to to put different phantoms all over the place, which is pretty cumbersome. Also, I'd like to avoid any way of manual spacing, like `\;`, `\,` etc., because I don't know which one would be the right one and it also seems to be a dirty workaround rather than the optimal solution.

What is the underlying problem here, and how can I solve it? I'd appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What you note is that `=` is defined as an operator which adds space to the left and right if there are operands. If you put it into a phanom-box, no space will be added. A quick fix would be `\hphantom{{}={}}`, with `{}` taking the role of operands.

Comment: The problem is that the cell border separates the `=` and the letter and so the mathrel space is not added. Try `= {}&b` instead.

Comment: Putting `=` to the left of `&` runs a bit against the intended use of `align`. Maybe have a look into the `amsmath` documentation and use `aligned` or something similar to arrange the parts of your equation. If you are not satisfied in the end, it may help to show us the whole equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly related to `&` you see this in an example just using inline math

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

1 $a=b$

2 {$a=$}{$b$}

3 {$a={}$}{$b$}

4 {$a$}{${}=b$}

\end{document}
```

In an AMS alignment, odd numbered columns are set as `\hfil$\displaystyle#$` so right aligned displaystyle math. Even numbered columns are set as `$\displaystyle{}#$\hfil` so left aligned, but with a leading `{}` so that `&=` aligns on `=` while keeping the `\mathrel` spacing.

So, to align after the operator, you need to add the `{}`, and use `={}&`